# how to create multiple radial bar inside each other?

Tags: flutter, charts

I need to make a multiple radial bar inside each other. I searched but only  syncfusion_flutter_charts package had some thing like that but I it needs licenses .There is no limitation on using other flutter packages.
the chart is some thing like this [multiple radial bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcaJD.png)

Comment: use `CustomPaint` and draw your radial bars in `CustomPainter.paint` method

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/licensing/overview The License key registration is no longer required for Flutter from version 18.3.0.x. So, there is no need to generate or register Syncfusion Flutter license keys in your Flutter projects. You can use it with community license without license

Comment: use three percent_indicator 4.2.2 inside stack

Answer (score 1):

using this way you can achieve it ( this is only a example , how to do it , it is not a implementation code ) ,

write code according to the use case , that is add alignment ,positioned ,etc...

```
stack(children: [

CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 50.0,
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                progressColor: Colors.purple,
                .....
                .....

              ),
CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 100.0,
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                progressColor: Colors.red,
                .....
                .....
              ),

CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 150.0,
                circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                progressColor: Colors.blue,
                .....
                .....

              ),
])
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget together with [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) Widgets. Examples with guides are found in the added links by the Flutter team itself.

What You can do is, use Stack widget to stack the Widgets and use to Wrap those widgets in Positioned widget to Passioned them the way you want inside the Stack.

*Although I should mention heavy use of stack widget will have some performance impact.*

Answer (score 0):

actually I found the best way.CircularPercentIndicator has a center property which takes a widget. I gave it an another CircularPercentIndicator .this way worked perfect